# Python infinite loop and if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

**The question requires me to determine the output of the following code.**

```
def new_if(pred, then_clause, else_clause):

    if pred:
        then_clause
    else:
        else_clause
def p(x):
    new_if(x>5, print(x), p(2*x))  
p(1)
```

I dont understand why it will be an infinite loop.
of output 1,2,4,8,16....and so on.

From what i understand, passing print(x) as a parameter will
straightaway print x, that is why the output has 1,2,4 even though the predicate is not True.

What i dont understand is after x>5, when pred is True,
Why the function does not end at the  if pred:
Is it because there is no return value? Even after i put return then_clause or else_clause it is still an infinite loop.

I am unable to test this on pythontutor as it is infinite recursion.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: this code never actually enters the `new_if` function.

Comment: You are passing the result of calling `p(2*x)` to `new_if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't let you pass expressions like `x > 5` as code to other functions (at least, not directly as the code is trying to do). If you call a function like `foo(x > 5)`, the `x > 5` expression is evaluated immediately in the caller's scope and only the *result* of the evaluation is passed to the function being called. The same happens for function calls within other function calls. When Python sees `foo(bar())`, it calls `bar` first, then calls `foo` with `bar`'s return value.

In the `p(x)` function, the code is trying to pass `p(2*x)` to the `new_if` function, but the interpreter never gets to `new_if` since the `p` calls keep recursing forever (or rather until an exception is raised for exceeding the maximum recursion depth).

One way to make the code work would be to put the expressions into `lambda` functions, and changing `new_if` to call them. Bundling the code up into a function lets you delay the evaluation of the expression until the function is called, and there's no infinite recursion since `pred_func` is generally going to return `True` at some point (though it will still recurse forever if you call something like `p(0)` or `p(-1)`):

```
def new_if(pred_func, then_func, else_func):
    if pred_func():
        then_func()
    else:
        else_func()

def p(x):
    new_if(lambda: x>5, lambda: print(x), lambda: p(2*x))
```

Note that `lambda`s feel a little bit odd to me for `then_func` or `else_func`, since we don't care about or use the return values from them at all. A `lambda` function always returns the result of its expression. That's actually pretty harmless in this case, since both `print` and `p` return `None` anyway, which is the same as what Python would return for us if we didn't explicitly `return` from a regular (non-`lambda`) function. But for me at least, it seems more natural to use a `lambda` when the return value means something. (Perhaps `new_if` should `return` the value returned from whichever function it calls?)

If you don't like writing closures (i.e. functions that have to look up `x` in the enclosing scope), you could instead use `functools.partial` to bind pre-calculated arguments to functions like `print` and `p` without calling those functions immediately. For instance:

```
from functools import partial

def p(x):
    return new_if(partial((5).__lt__, x), partial(print, x), partial(p, 2*x))
```

This only works if each of the expressions can be turned into a single call to an existing function. It can be done in this case (with a little creativity and careful syntax for `pred_func`), but probably won't be possible in more complicated cases.

Its also worth noting that the evaluation of `2*x` happens immediately in the `p` function's scope, before `new_if` is called. If that multiplication was the expensive part of the `else_func` logic, that could be problematic (you'd want to defer the work to when `else_func` was actually called).

Answer (score 1):

you are calling function from itself, that causes infinite loop and you have nothing to stop the function.

```
def new_if(pred, then_clause, else_clause):
    if pred:
        then_clause
    else:
        else_clause
def p(x):
    if x<5:
        new_if(x>5, print(x),p(2*x))    
p(1)
```

this will solve it